# Restrict supported devices on App Store / Google Play

Tags: mobile, app-store, google-play

Is it possible to restrict supported devices (only smartphones or tablets) on App Store / Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do it. When you go to developer console, there is an option to select the devices you want to support.

When you expand the supported devices option inside developers console, you get the list all devices which can currently run your application. You can include/exclude devices over there.

**Edited**:
there's already an dicussion on that -
[How to restrict android app to specific device make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510649/how-to-restrict-android-app-to-specific-device-make)

Comment: App Store?? u mean apple? well not sure of that. but how i see is all apple devices comes under same smartphone or tablet category. And since apple iOS is not open-source, device compatibilty shouldn't be a issue. Not sure though.

Comment: Target a higher iOS version as that will exclude older devices from being able to run your app.