# Make application available only for samsung

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app and want to it make available only for Samsung devices. With the device availability dialog, I must exclude each device. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510649/how-to-restrict-android-app-to-specific-device-make

Comment: Short of toggling devices off individually, there is no other way to restrict distribution to a single manufacturer via the Play Store. What you want is not exactly a common pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String str = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;` to get device name or `android.os.Build.MODEL`. Validate result and show any Dialog box on `false`, after - close your activity.

Other way, configure market publisher to block other devices

Comment: Configuring market publisher is a good idea but there are more than 1500 devices available for my application and it is very unconfortable to exclude all devices

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) It contains almost everything you need to know about the users device.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mf = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

if (mf.equals("samsung")) {
    //device is samsung
} else {
    //device not samsung
}
```

Comment: In fact Build.MANUFACTURER for Samsung is "samsung" with lower-case "s" so the code would not work..