# Filter publised android application by spefic devices on google play store

Tags: android, filter, google-play

I have android app published on google play store. it is visible to all users in USA. But now i want to publish my application so that only specific devices can install this application. 
For this purpose, i googled a lot but not getting anything. what i found is "Google play store private channel". I tried to understand that but no luck.

I think google play private channel restrict application to specific user not devices.

Am i right ?

Please guide for the same.

Comment: When you say you want to restrict installation, do you mean also that you want to restrict visibility on the Google Play store to only the 50 devices that you mention in your comment to Stevie754's question?  Or do you mean that the installation should fail for all but those 50 devices?

Also, when you say 50 devices, identified by deviceID, do you mean 50 physical units, as opposed to 50 models of device perhaps encompassing thousands of device instances?  Stevie754 seems to be thinking the latter, but I'm suspecting you mean the former.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html 
 take a look at this link, it tells you how to restrict certain devices installing or viewing your app in the play store. You can restrict access by sdk version or screen size.

Comment: I already read out that page but it is not as per my requirment what i want to publish for only 50 specific device.Device must identified by deviceID.

Comment: You don't need to filter your app based on device/manufacturer in the application code, instead you can do it from the android market developer console - https://market.android.com/publish/ just when you publish the app itself.

There is a 'Supported Devices' section on the developer console, which shows you a list of all the devices which can access the android market.

"Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510649/how-to-restrict-android-app-to-specific-device-make" PLease go and give Soham an upvote if this is what you were looking