# How to restrict app to specific devices ?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am writing a media player application. It is best to see in 10 inch tablet, 7 inch tablet, 5 inch phone. So I wanna restrict my app to install to those devices only. How can I do that?

Here are my current manifest file values

```
<application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_new"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:name="VideoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">

           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>


    </application>
```

Comment: Have you seen <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510649/how-to-restrict-android-app-to-specific-device-make>

Comment: Thanks.. that link is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Add the following things on your `AndroidManifest.xml` before `<application>` tag :

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
              android:normalScreens="false"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

You can also follow the reference links::

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html

[image]

The above code automatically filters devices by Play Store.

Comment: ok... But this attribute android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" is for 7inch tablet. So will it allow to install on 5 inch screen

Comment: @saa android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" this is just example, you can change this by your own. It's not mandatory to put 600 . You can replace with 480

Comment: @saa no, it tells that device minimum requirement will be 480. If the device has more than that , then it will support for this device also, but not for less than 480. Generally 5 inch screens start with 480dp . So , I have assigned 480

Comment: ok... i got it. thanks. Let me try your code. Then i will let you know if there are any issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46336/discussion-between-saa-and-satyaki-mukherjee)

Comment: what will be the integer values in these attributes android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"

Comment: @saa these two lines,i.e., android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer" is not necessary... if you want, then you can provide these lines......

Comment: @saa if my answer will help you , then please accept my answer, which will boost me up :)

Comment: Actually i dont know whether it is right answer or not. I have to upload my app to store to test it. It may take one more week to verify your answer.

Comment: @saa but you can test this before upload it to playstore . GO to APK on Developer console , see the supported device. On there give a name of normal screen mobile of "samsung galaxy y" or anything else. You can able to see this.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee I want my app to be available for only mobile devices & 7-inch tablets. By your answer, I got how to do that. But what if **screen compatibility mode** got activated?
I want my app to be shown on play store to mobile & 7-inch tablets users only & not to 9 & 10-inch tablet users.