# Only allow Android apps to be installed on certain devices

Tags: android

Basically, I want to make an Android app only isnstallable on certain devices. Let's say for example, my app should only be installed on the 2012 Nexus 7. Is there any way I can make it so that the app manifest only parses on the 2012 Nexus 7?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about specific devices but apps can be for a certain andriod OS. It can also be made for certain hardware specifications e.g. outwards facing camera.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the Play Store when you publish your app. You're able to choose the supported devices, et cetera.

Read [**this answer on StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510829/3488916), which looks pretty much like the thing that you're looking for. Another link you could check out is [**this one**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-essentials-publishing-to-specific-devices--mobile-9486).

Comment: This is not good enough as I am building a dangerous root app that only works on a very specific hardware config. I could have sworn there was some way in manifest to check build.prop settings before parsing the package. Also I want to make a version for devices that aren't officially supported by Play Store so they aren't in the dev console menus...