# How to set android for phones/tablets only?

Tags: android

I hear that android apps can now be played on a desktop in chrome os. The problem is that my app requires use of the accelerometer so it must be played in a hand held device. I don't want people downloading it on a desktop, getting mad because it doesn't work, then down-voting it. Thanks.

Comment: The answer here may also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510649/how-to-restrict-android-app-to-specific-device-make

Comment: Just a reminder: you as the developer need to specifically upload your app to the Chrome Web Store to have it available on Chrome OS - there's nothing automatic about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Adding this in your manifest, google will take care of everything `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />`

as said here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

> Google Play filters the applications that are visible to users, so
>   that users can see and download only those applications that are
>   compatible with their devices. One of the ways it filters applications
>   is by feature compatibility.