# How to filter the supporting android device at the time of publishing the android app?

Tags: android

I had finished my android app. App build version is 4.1.2. Now, i uploaded my apk into google console, it displays more that 4000 supporting devices. I am not sure my app will work on all the 4000 devices or not. My app is developed only for mobile.Can any one guide me how to filter the supporting devices ? Do i need any configuration in manifest file ?
please, look at my manifest file:-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application>
......
....
<activity
.....
...../>
<application/>
```

Answer (score 0):

*No need of any changes,the permission which you have given in manifest on that it will calculate the supporting device so better you remove the permissions which are not required and recheck ....it may show the less...
NOTE :Example permissions like:Remove which are not required....

Answer (score 0):

While publishing the apk there is an option for you to see in apk section the list of devices to be supported. You can view the devices supported and exclude them from the list. Pl. refer to the below stack overflow link it provides you all the option
[How to restrict android app to specific device make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510649/how-to-restrict-android-app-to-specific-device-make)