# Multiple apk versionCode distinction

Tags: android, android-ndk, multiple-apk

I have an application that supports both x86 and arm-v7 platforms. 
I should define different `android:versionCode` for different platform apks. Therefore I put for example 100 and 200 in value and upload an apk to Google Play. The issue in devices that support both platforms. If a device on x86 supports arm and the `android:versionCode` of the arm apk greater than the same code for the x86-version apk, it downloads the arm apk, not x86. Arm libs work much more slower, at least 5 times in my app. How can i solve that issue?
I want to install the x86-version only on the x86 platform devices, and analogically for the arm ones.
Any suggestions?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#MultiApks

Did you tried, setting up filters as suggested like here ?

Comment: Did you see any filters that look usable for my situation?  I didn't. I need to know how to forbid download the version that is not fit natively to platform, because hardware emulation is slow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9510829/3035416. Refer this, currently I dont have a google play account to show you the steps. But this is how you may have to do.

Comment: Seems to be useful. I'll try to investigate your link and write report. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 devices are able to handle ARM libs but there is no ARM device able to handle x86 libs.

So you only have to keep the version code of your x86 APK higher than the one of your ARM apk, and the right APK will go to the right device.