# Android - exclude all but certain devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

How do you publish an Android app on the Play Store that exclude all but certain device?

Is this done in manifest settings or in the Play Store Dashboard? If so, is there a quicker way than manually excluding 900+ devices

Note, the linked question does not explain if there are batch commands to easily exclude a whole class of devices - instead of manually selecting 9000+ devices

Comment: Not a duplicate as the linked question does not solve the batch select

Comment: Not the accepted answer, but the answer by Desty. It's a firebug hack, but it seems have done the trick. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18638583/320111 Anyone, please feel free to copy Desty's answer here with a reference to it.  Since the original question wasn't asking precisely about that and since the original asker didn't accept that specific answer, I can see why many people would miss it.