# Android Studio - How to not allow users with sw720 download my app

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

No matter what I do, the sw720 screen sizes look awful. I'm wondering if there is a way to not allow users with this screen size to download the app.

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you create a 720 version ?

Comment: I have a 720 version. Just with such a hard width its impossible for this app to look presentable.

Comment: If the problem is that the contents are too many for such a little screen, then you should change the design for it and do it again.

Comment: Ok, let me re-phrase this for a similar problem. I do not want to produce my app for the galaxy watch. How do I not allow it to be downloaded on the watch.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510649/how-to-restrict-android-app-to-specific-device-make) is all I can help you.

Comment: Create an answer then and mark it as solved :) To avoid more comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<compatible-screens>` tag in your manifest by this way, you can decide the screen size and screenDensity that your app compatible with.
This is the example:
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html
and that all the filter you can use in your manifest:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html